# Insert your own code into another project automatically

Tags: c, makefile

I'm making use of an open source project that is changing quite frequently. It is necessary for me to always have the latest version with all changes and bug fixes.

The source code has been adjusted to make it do what I need. So it now contains my own code as well. Whenever sth changes, I currently manually read what changed in the changelog or compare files and then copy and paste everything into my own files. This is quite time consuming.

So now I was thinking about using a different approach:

1. Instead of long code snippets, only insert function calls and keep all of them in a separate file. Add this file to the make system.
2. If the source code changes, download it and re-insert all the changes automatically
3. Recompile, done

This way I can now compare old and new (untouched) versions with the original source code and see what has changed between the state of the code that I used and the new one.

My question is for step 2:

Line numbers might change if additional code is added. How can I find the right positions to inject my own functions?

Comment: Use source control. Branch your version from the trunk, and then merge in changes from the trunk as it changes.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I didn't know I could create my own branches. I now read up on it and this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Frank: it depends on the source control system used by the project you've forked (hereafter called "upstream"). If it doesn't let you, then the usual thing is to create a branch in your own source control for code from upstream. Then create branches from this for your changes. Each time new code arrives from upstream, first you check it into your upstream branch, then you merge the changes on that branch into your development branch. There might still be conflicts that you have to resolve manually, but the merge does a lot of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks Steve, very helpful advice. The system they use is CVS.

Comment: @Frank: right, so unless they give you permission, you can't just go into their repository and create a branch. With decentralized source-control (e.g. `git`), you could create your own local branch that's absolutely none of their business. If you're checking their source into your system, then just because they use CVS doesn't mean you have to, so that's a win right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as the Jonathan says. Use source control.

Comment: I AM THE JONATHAN. KNEEL BEFORE ME. :)